# How to filter dimension values when fetching data from Google Analytics into PowerQuery/PowerBi

Tags: google-analytics, powerbi, powerquery

I want to fetch data from Google Analytics With M (PowerQuery/PowerBI), but want to filter the dimension values on the fily, Let's Say my dimension is "Page" and I want "Pageviews" and "Unique Pageviews" measures, provided that the "Page" is following a regex filter (ex. `ga:pagePath=~^.*?([0-9]{6,7}|mpg[0-9]{1,3}){1}\.html[/]?[^ ]*`)

I could use "`Table.SelectRows`", but as M doesn't support regex, this filter should be passed to GA api directly. Here is what M generated for me:

```
    let
    Source = GoogleAnalytics.Accounts(),
    #"1234567" = Source{[Id="1234567"]}[Data],
    #"UA-987654-1" = #"1234567"{[Id="UA-52004541-1"]}[Data],
    #"11111" = #"UA-987654-1"{[Id="1234567"]}[Data],
    #"Added Items" = Cube.Transform(#"11111", {{Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "ga:pagePath", {"ga:pagePath"}, {"Page"}}, {Cube.AddMeasureColumn, "Pageviews", "ga:pageviews"}, {Cube.AddMeasureColumn, "Unique Pageviews", "ga:uniquePageviews"}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Items", each Text.Contains([Page], "html"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Is there any possiblity to pass my regex filter to GA api in M?

Comment: What do you mean by "on the fily" ?

Comment: Maybe you mean how to use filters? (no matter if there are regexps)

Comment: No, I don't want to fetch all data then select rows using filters (Data would be so big and taking so long to retrieve the data). I want to put regex filter on the Page dimension upon retrieving the data, just like an api call to GA with this filter `ga:pagePath=~^.*?([0-9]{6,7}|mpg[0-9]{1,3}){1}\.html[/]?[^ ]*)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your interest!

We don't support regular expression filters today. With Text filters you can generally implement the same filter logic, but admittedly it wouldn't be as concise as your regex.

We welcome requests for new features at https://ideas.powerbi.com, so consider starting a thread there :)

Comment: But this regex filtering should be processed by GA itself, no? I just want to know how I can pass filter argument to a GA api call

Comment: Our GA connector doesn't support letting you pass raw filters, sorry. Normally for features like this you'd express the filter as a M function, and then when executing the table we recognize that expression pattern and emit the source-specific filter expression. If passing raw filter expressions is the feature that you want, again, please create a new thread at https://ideas.powerbi.com :)